# How to set a (click) to <select> tag

Tags: html, css, angular

Angular 2, TS.

How to set `(click)="functionA()"` in `<option>` tag?

This construction not working.

```
 <select class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option (click)="functionA()">2</option>
      <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

And this to:

```
 <select class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option><a (click)="functionA()"><a>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a click event. Just add `(change)` in the selected.

```
 <select (change)="functionA()">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

EDIT: And if you want two functions executed as per comment, just add `;` in between:

```
 <select (change)="functionA(); functionB()">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: And if i would use two functions?

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: @EduardArevshatyan remember to mark the answer as accepted since you got a working solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `"` inside your constructor `(click)="functionA()>` code.

Add the missing `"` as :

```
 <select class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option (click)="functionA()">2</option>
      <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, typo, sorry.